# Oracle Turn 1 to many relationship into single rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 Oracle (Oracle 12) tables

```
StudentTable
s_id number
s_name varchar

Data in Table -->  1   Joe


ClassTable
c_student_id number
c_className varchar

Data in table -->  1   Math
                   1   History
                   1   Sceince
```

I want to write a query that will take the 3 rows and turn it into 1 comma delimited column.

I want my output to look like the following:

```
Joe    Math, History, Science
```

Is there a way to create this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX( s_name ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY s.s_id ) AS name,
       LISTAGG( c_class_name, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS classes
FROM   Students s
       INNER JOIN
       Classes c
       ON ( s.s_id = c.c_student_id )
GROUP BY s.s_id;
```

Comment: Why do you need to keep dense_rank? max(s_name) should suffice. Also, perhaps the inner join should be a left outer join, to allow for students with no associated courses - so that the output list would include all students.